# How to conditionally include list elements in React Component

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, jsx

I am working with a component that renders a dictionary list. I want to optionally pass in a prop that would insert an additional list element.

```
...
render() {
    return (
        <dl>
          !! Optional !!
          <dt>{this.props.optionalPropObj.label}</dt>
          <dd>{this.props.optionalPropObj.value}</dd>
          !! Optional !!

          <dt>Label One</dt>
          <dd>{this.props.foo.one}</dd>

          <dt>Label Two</dt>
          <dd>{this.props.foo.two}</dd>

          <dt>Label Three</dt>
          <dd>{this.props.foo.Three}</dd>

          ...

        </dl>
    );
}
```

There are a few ways to do this, but I want to minimize the logic footprint for this behavior. The main problem is because React needs a wrapping element and the `<dt>` and `<dd>` are child elements.

I could split into two returns, which is horribly inefficient:

```
...
if (this.props.optionalPropObj) {
    return (
        <dl>
          // Include optional prop list element
        </dl>
    );
} else {
    return (
        <dl>
          // Exclude optional prop list element
        </dl>
    );
}
```

I could hide them with a css class, but then I have 4 conditionals:

```
return (
    <dl>
      <dt className={this.props.optionalPropObj ? '' : 'hidden'}>
        {this.props.optionalPropObj && this.props.optionalPropObj.label}
      </dt>
      <dd className={this.props.optionalPropObj ? '' : 'hidden'}>
        {this.props.optionalPropObj && this.props.optionalPropObj.value}
      </dd>
    </dl>
);
```

If I could wrap the elements in a div, this situation would be trivial.

```
return (
    ...
    {includeOptional && <OptionalThing />}
    or
    {includeOptional ? <OptionalThing /> : null}
    ...
);
```

Ideally, I want a way to check for the optional prop once and include the extra element without any code duplication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out a way to do it with valid Html output. You conditionally include an array of elements. Since the only valid child elements of a `<dl>` tag are `<dt>` and `<dd>`, I needed a way to add the fragment without a wrapper.

```
render() {
    return (
       <dl>
         { 
            this.props.optionalPropObj &&
            [
               <dt key="optionalPropLabel">{this.props.optionalPropObj.label}</dt>,
               <dd key="optionalPropValue">{this.props.optionalPropObj.value}</dd>
            ]
         }

         <dt>Label One</dt>
         <dd>{this.props.foo.one}</dd>

         <dt>Label Two</dt>
         <dd>{this.props.foo.two}</dd>

         <dt>Label Three</dt>
         <dd>{this.props.foo.Three}</dd>

         ...

       </dl>
    );
}
```

Edit: Since I'm rendering an array, React wants keys for each element, so I added in some dummy keys. I'm only displaying one of these on a page at a time, so my requirements allow them to be static.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this

```
render() {
    return (
        <dl>
          { 
           this.props.optionalPropObj &&
            <span>
              <dt>{this.props.optionalPropObj.label}</dt>
              <dd>{this.props.optionalPropObj.value}</dd>
            </span>
          }

          <dt>Label One</dt>
          <dd>{this.props.foo.one}</dd>

          <dt>Label Two</dt>
          <dd>{this.props.foo.two}</dd>

          <dt>Label Three</dt>
          <dd>{this.props.foo.Three}</dd>

          ...

        </dl>
    );
}
```

Comment: Yes. That's the same as my last example. I want to create something like a document fragment in jsx, so I only check the condition once.

Comment: I wasn't sure if it was valid html to wrap with a span, but I may settle on this if my compiler/linter doesn't whine and there are no other native options. It would be really nice to have native fragment support, though.

Comment: @Jecoms span is a valid HTML wrap. Don't need to worry!